# How to use Nullable types in c++/cli?

Tags: c++-cli

I have the following code, which I thought would work:

```
property Nullable<double> Angle {
    Nullable<double> get() {
        return nullptr;
    }
}
```

It doesn't. How can I do it? Does c++/CLI even support nullable types?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

OK, found it, after a lot of hassle:

to return null, just do

```
return Nullable<double>();
```

to return non-null:

```
return Nullable<double>(12321);
```

It is important to declare the return value as `Nullable<double>` and not `Nullable<double>^`, as if you do it, when using other languages as C# and vb.net, you'll see the type as `ValueType` instead of `double?`.

Comment: If anyone wondered, `Nullable<double>^` contains a handle to a boxed instance of `double`, or a value of `nullptr`, not an instance of `Nullable<double>`. C# etc. doesn't support boxed value types signatures, and thus only sees `ValueType` (though in metadata, the original type is preserved). Nullable types cannot be boxed with their actual value, only with their inner value or as literal null.