# Call c# from c++: how to pass nullptr to DateTime?

Tags: c#, c++-cli, nullable

In a c# assembly, I got a function taking a nullable DateTime as parameter:

```
public void DoSomething(DateTime? timestamp);
```

Now I want to call this method from c++/cli:

```
MyClass->DoSomething(nullptr);
```

This will not compile. Instead the c++ compiler will print an error message nullptr can not be converted to System::Nullable.

So how do I pass nullptr from c++ to a nullable DateTime?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
MyClass->DoSomething(Nullable<DateTime>());
```

[How to use Nullable types in c++/cli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457723/how-to-use-nullable-types-on-c-cli)

Comment: Duh. Obviously I was thinking way too complicated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

`Nullable` is a *value type* and C++/CLI doesn’t provide compile-time magic for it. You need to go the explicit route:

```
System::Nullable<System::DateTime> dtnull;
MyClass->DoSomething(dtnull);
```

Of course, you can also use a temporary here:

```
MyClass->DoSomething(System::Nullable<System::DateTime>());
```