# C++ Nullable/optionable integer to be used with vectors

Tags: c++, android-ndk, nullable

I am using NDK on Android, I was hoping get something similar to a List on Java, where elements can be null values. I know in C++ null is different to Java, so I am after where having a value for the element is optional.

I know Boost has **Boost.Optional**, I don't want to add this library just for this. 
I have seen code like this `return Nullable<double>();` on stackoverflow
[How to use Nullable types in c++/cli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457723/how-to-use-nullable-types-in-c-cli)
but I think that is only for MS Visual C++, when I write similar code it says Nullable could not be resolved.

I am using STLPort library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is 32-bit `int` we're talking about. What is the nature of your variables - are you sure all 4294967296 possible values are equally possible and valid? In the vast majority of cases, you can designate a particular int value - zero, or -1, or a billion - as a "nonvalue", and treat it the way you'd treat a null. Think hard about your list, see if you can pick a value that can't possibly appear in the list, and if there is one, treat it as a null.

The only use case that I can think of where all possible int values are equally valid is 32-bit hashes or checksums (like CRC32).

All else failing, it's fairly easy to spin your own implementation of a nullable primitive. The basics would go like this:

```
template<typename T>
class Nullable<T>
{
    T _Value;
    bool _IsNull;
public:

    Nullable<T>();
    Nullable<T>(T);
    Nullable<T>(Nullable<T> &);
    Nullable<T> &operator=(Nullable<T> &);
    Nullable<T> &operator=(T);

    operator T(); //Value extractor
    bool IsNull(); //Nullity extractor
};
```

And so forth. You won't need a destructor. You can even throw an exception if they're trying to extract the value from a null object.

Comment: True, for the time being, I just used a value that wasn't being used as the null value to check for. But I would prefer something that was similar to Java as it would make porting the code simpler. Thanks

Comment: Java, for the record, imposes a boxing penalty for converting between primitive types (like `int`) and their nullable counterparts (`Integer`). Also, in Java, you can't instantiate generics over primitive types. In C++, you can.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Null Object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) or store (smart) pointer in the list.