# How to pass System::Nullable<int> from C++/CLI to int? in C# as a method paramter

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli, clr, nullable

I have a method in a C# Class Lib named testLib.dll:

```
namespace testLib
{
     public class Converter
     {
          public void Func_int2(int? a = null)
          {
          //whatever it does
          }
     }
}
```

and I want to call this method by C++/CLI, I know that `int?` is actually `Nullable<int>` in C# ,so I tried codes like this:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace testLib;

int main()
{
    Nullable<int>^ a = gcnew Nullable<int>();
    testLib::Converter^ converter;
    converter->Func_int2(a);
}
```

it shows error:

```
E1767   function "testLib::Converter::Func_int2" cannot be called with the given argument list
```

And I tired many other ways but failed.
How can I call the method with a `int?` param ,any one teach me plz?

Comment: Never used C++/CLI, but try without `gcnew`ing the nullable; just pass it by value (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1457752/21567)).

Comment: Yes, @Christian.K is right - it's odd to use a managed pointer for a value type - just use: Nullable<int> a();

Comment: Nullable is a struct, a value type.  So you must not use the ^ hat in the declaration.

Comment: THX everyone,I tired to use Nullable<int> a(),but the param still doesn't fit the method.I think it'a maybe not a good idea to use C++/CLI,I will never use it again unless i had no choice.